# BIRT Report through BIRT Report Viewer on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, birt, birt-deapi

I am a newbie to BIRT and Tomcat Development.

I have deployed the BIRT Report Viewer on Tomcat and restarted the Tomcat.

The Tomcat and the birt-viewer both are working fine.

The simple report is working fine on OpenText Analytics BIRT Designer.

However when I try to access this simple basic report from the Viewer through this url

`http://localhost:8084/birt-viewer/run?__report=Report\sample.rptdesign&param=my+parameter`

I get the following Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1115)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2392)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)

   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/datatools/connectivity/oda/OdaException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2899)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineFactory.createDataEngine(DataEngineFactory.java:46)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.DataEngine.newDataEngine(DataEngine.java:194)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.DataEngine.newDataEngine(DataEngine.java:172)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:190)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataAdapterFactory.createSession(DataAdapterFactory.java:30)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.DataRequestSession.newSession(DataRequestSession.java:85)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.DataRequestSession.newSession(DataRequestSession.java:64)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.(DteDataEngine.java:104)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.DataEngineFactory.createDataEngine(DataEngineFactory.java:115)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.openDataEngine(ExecutionContext.java:891)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.getDataEngine(ExecutionContext.java:908)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:122)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:42)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportExecutor.java:61)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:179)
```

Development Environment:

Java JDK : 1.8.0

Apache Tomcat : 7.0.41

Open Text Analytic Designer : 4.6.0

Please help me understand the error from this Stack Trace and also resolve this issue.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/datatools/connectivity/oda/OdaException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException)  the exception couldnt actually be handled properly because the Exception class isnt available....

Comment: Also you already asked this question why did you post it twice....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254758/birt-report-viewer-on-tomcat-for-birt-report

Answer (score 0):

When birt viewer is deployed correctly in apache tomcat , one can immediately test the successful installation using following URL( edit the Port Number that is set in local container in conf/*server.xml* )

http://localhost:8079/birt-viewer/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&sample=my+parameter

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried running the test.rptdesign file on the Birt Viewer, and still face the same error.

So just for Trial purpose, I tried installing the BirtViewer and Tomcat on a Linux Machine and both the reports worked like a Charm. :)